# Is there a good way to do iterative DFS with postfix evaluation of the node?

Tags: javascript, depth-first-search

Here is what the code looks like:

```
var initial = [2,3,5];
var cache = {}, pile = [];
pile.push(initial);
while (pile.length > 0) {
    var e = pile.pop();
    var value, k = key(e);
    if (k in cache) {
        value = cache[k];
    } else {
        var chs = make_children(e);
        chs.forEach((c) => (pile.push(c)));

        value = 0; // calculated from the children, 
                   // but the children are not calculated yet

        /*do something with value here*/

        cache[k] = value;
    }
}
```

Note: You can assume that the data doesn't cycle (no loop).

How can I reassemble the parent value from it's children without using recursion (too costly because it's very deep)? Also, I would like not to have to create a tree structure.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: The wanted result is a general algorithm that use iteration like recursion so i can do postfix eveluation of the current node after evaluation it's children.